# Bluetooth Crash on Samsung S4

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, android-ibeacon

I am running an application with BLE scan. on Samsung S4 after a while or if more tha 10 beacons are around I see this error:

```
    07-18 11:51:57.169: W/bt_userial(7819): userial_read_thread() failed to gain buffers
    07-18 11:51:57.169: E/GKI_LINUX(7819): ##### ERROR : GKI_exception: GKI_exception():    Task State Table
    07-18 11:51:57.169: E/GKI_LINUX(7819): #####
    07-18 11:51:57.169: E/GKI_LINUX(7819): ##### ERROR : GKI_exception: TASK ID [0] task name [BTU] state [1]
    07-18 11:51:57.169: E/GKI_LINUX(7819): #####
    07-18 11:51:57.169: E/GKI_LINUX(7819): ##### ERROR : GKI_exception: TASK ID [1] task name [BTIF] state [1]
   07-18 11:51:57.169: E/GKI_LINUX(7819): #####
   07-18 11:51:57.169: E/GKI_LINUX(7819): ##### ERROR : GKI_exception: TASK ID [2] task name [A2DP-MEDIA] state [1]
   07-18 11:51:57.169: E/GKI_LINUX(7819): #####
   07-18 11:51:57.169: E/GKI_LINUX(7819): ##### ERROR : GKI_exception: GKI_exception 65524 getbuf: out of buffers#####
   07-18 11:51:57.169: E/GKI_LINUX(7819): ##### ERROR : GKI_exception: 
   07-18 11:51:57.169: E/GKI_LINUX(7819):     ********************************************************************
   07-18 11:51:57.169: E/GKI_LINUX(7819): #####
   07-18 11:51:57.169: E/GKI_LINUX(7819): ##### ERROR : GKI_exception: * GKI_exception():       65524 getbuf: out of buffers
   07-18 11:51:57.169: E/GKI_LINUX(7819): #####
   07-18 11:51:57.169: E/GKI_LINUX(7819): ##### ERROR : GKI_exception: ********************************************************************
   07-18 11:51:57.169: E/GKI_LINUX(7819): #####
   07-18 11:51:57.209: E/MP-Decision(1831): num online cores: 3 reqd : 2 available : 4   rq_depth:1.700000 hotplug_avg_load_dw: 28
   07-18 11:51:57.209: E/MP-Decision(1831): DOWN cpu:2 core_idx:2 Ns:2.100000 Ts:240 total_time_down:287.000000
   07-18 11:51:57.269: W/bt_userial(7819): userial_read_thread() failed to gain buffers
   07-18 11:51:57.269: E/GKI_LINUX(7819): ##### ERROR : GKI_exception: GKI_exception(): Task State Table
   07-18 11:51:57.269: E/GKI_LINUX(7819): #####
   07-18 11:51:57.269: E/GKI_LINUX(7819): ##### ERROR : GKI_exception: TASK ID [0] task name [BTU] state [1]
   07-18 11:51:57.269: E/GKI_LINUX(7819): #####
   07-18 11:51:57.269: E/GKI_LINUX(7819): ##### ERROR : GKI_exception: TASK ID [1] task name [BTIF] state [1]
   07-18 11:51:57.269: E/GKI_LINUX(7819): #####
   07-18 11:51:57.269: E/GKI_LINUX(7819): ##### ERROR : GKI_exception: TASK ID [2] task name [A2DP-MEDIA] state [1]
   07-18 11:51:57.269: E/GKI_LINUX(7819): #####
   07-18 11:51:57.269: E/GKI_LINUX(7819): ##### ERROR : GKI_exception: GKI_exception 65524 getbuf: out of buffers#####
   07-18 11:51:57.269: E/GKI_LINUX(7819): ##### ERROR : GKI_exception: 
   07-18 11:51:57.269: E/GKI_LINUX(7819): ********************************************************************
   07-18 11:51:57.269: E/GKI_LINUX(7819): #####
   07-18 11:51:57.269: E/GKI_LINUX(7819): ##### ERROR : GKI_exception: * GKI_exception():  65524 getbuf: out of buffers
   07-18 11:51:57.269: E/GKI_LINUX(7819): #####
   07-18 11:51:57.269: E/GKI_LINUX(7819): ##### ERROR : GKI_exception: ********************************************************************
   07-18 11:51:57.269: E/GKI_LINUX(7819): #####
   07-18 11:51:57.349: D/InputReader(694): Input event: value=1 when=961943015000
   07-18 11:51:57.349: I/InputReader(694): Touch event's action is 0x0 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=0.153 ] when=961943076000
   07-18 11:51:57.349: I/InputDispatcher(694): Delivering touch to: action: 0x0
   07-18 11:51:57.349: I/InputDispatcher(694): Delivering touch to: action: 0x0
   07-18 11:51:57.359: I/power(694): *** acquire_dvfs_lock : lockType : 1  freq : 1458000 
   07-18 11:51:57.359: D/SSRMv2:CustomFrequencyManagerService(694): acquireDVFSLockLocked :  type : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 1458000  uid : 10048  pid : 1144  pkgName : com.sec.android.app.launcher@1
   07-18 11:51:57.369: W/bt_userial(7819): userial_read_thread() failed to gain buffers
   07-18 11:51:57.369: E/GKI_LINUX(7819): ##### ERROR : GKI_exception: GKI_exception(): Task State Table
   07-18 11:51:57.369: E/GKI_LINUX(7819): #####
   07-18 11:51:57.369: E/GKI_LINUX(7819): ##### ERROR : GKI_exception: TASK ID [0] task name [BTU] state [1]
   07-18 11:51:57.369: E/GKI_LINUX(7819): #####
   07-18 11:51:57.369: E/GKI_LINUX(7819): ##### ERROR : GKI_exception: TASK ID [1] task name [BTIF] state [1]
   07-18 11:51:57.369: E/GKI_LINUX(7819): #####
   07-18 11:51:57.369: E/GKI_LINUX(7819): ##### ERROR : GKI_exception: TASK ID [2] task name [A2DP-MEDIA] state [1]
   07-18 11:51:57.369: E/GKI_LINUX(7819): #####
   07-18 11:51:57.369: E/GKI_LINUX(7819): ##### ERROR : GKI_exception: GKI_exception 65524  getbuf: out of buffers#####
   07-18 11:51:57.369: E/GKI_LINUX(7819): ##### ERROR : GKI_exception: 
   07-18 11:51:57.369: E/GKI_LINUX(7819):  ********************************************************************
   07-18 11:51:57.369: E/GKI_LINUX(7819): #####
   07-18 11:51:57.369: E/GKI_LINUX(7819): ##### ERROR : GKI_exception: * GKI_exception(): 65524 getbuf: out of buffers
   07-18 11:51:57.369: E/GKI_LINUX(7819): #####
   07-18 11:51:57.369: E/GKI_LINUX(7819): ##### ERROR : GKI_exception: ********************************************************************
   07-18 11:51:57.369: E/GKI_LINUX(7819): #####
   07-18 11:51:57.369: D/SSRMv2:Monitor(694): SIOP:: AP = 380 (read only)
```

The issue happens even though my application is not running. If I turn Bluetooth on and more than 20 BLE devices are around the error occurs and the phone become very slow. 
any sugestion for solving this issue?

Comment: Can you include some logging messages that show where your app makes BLE calls?   It would be useful to see the interlacing between those and these, and if the process ID in () matches, indicating if this is system library code that runs in your app or system code that runs in a system process (or possibly something independent and only coincidentally related).

Comment: I have added complete log but the error is present even without my application running.

Comment: Then it probably has nothing to do with your project.